# How to fix array method for finding if elements in one array exist in another in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am attempting to solve a problem where if the elements in one array are squared, and all of the new elements are found in array 2, then return true, otherwise return false.  My code looks right but it gets caught up whenever 1 number is very close to the square of another.

Here is my code:

```
function comp(arr1, arr2){
  let a1 = arr1.sort((a, b) => a - b).map(x => x*x);
  let a2 = arr2.sort((a, b) => a - b);

  return a1.filter(x => !a2.includes(x)).length === 0 ? true : false
}
```

When I test it on repl, with

```
arr1 = [91, 15, 54, 53, 78, 80, 91]; 

arr2 = [8281, 225, 2916, 2809, 6084, 6400, 8282];
```

I get true for some reason even though it should be false.  However other tested arrays for arr1 and arr2 pass, it just randomly fails.  Is my code incorrect?

Comment: Have you logged the result of that `.filter()` call to see what's in that array?

Comment: Why do you need to sort?

Comment: @adiga `8281` the first element in the second array, so `includes()` would be true, no?

Comment: @Taplar if you sort the array you need not to do multiple looping to check the matched value. you can easily match the values based on index

Comment: No arr2 is supposed to be different, I should be getting false dude to the 8282.  I guess I don't need to sort, pretty new to vanilla javascript.  yeah the filter portion without the .length and everything after returns and empty array.

Comment: @CodeManiac that's assuming that both arrays are the same number of elements, and that the positions should relate elements.  That seems to change the context of the question.

Comment: @SohelPatel you won't get `false` because `arr2 ` includes `8281`

Comment: square of 91 is 8281 which is is available in arr2

Comment: @Taplar you're right, I got confused with when OP wanted `true` and `false`

Comment: @Taplar yeah agree these become two complete different contexts.

Comment: @SohelPatel As you can see from the comments, there is some confusion.  Should the position of the elements be important in the evaluation, or just that the value exists at all?

Comment: Position does not matter, just that if it exists, I already see 1 problem in my method, I figured filter would return the element that doesn't exist in a2, but that was an oversight on my part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT (see edit history for original that fails if there are duplicates in the first array):

Your original code works (at least for the example inputs). You are just doing more than necessary to get the output.

The input array included in your question...

```
[91, 15, 54, 53, 78, 80, 91]
```

...results in the following array after squaring the values:

```
[8281, 225, 2916, 2809, 6084, 6400, 8281]
```

All of these squared values are included in your comparison array (which also contains one additional value that is not generated by squaring the input array):

```
[8281, 225, 2916, 2809, 6084, 6400, 8282]
```

A slightly simpler approach would be to square the values in the first array and then use `every` and `includes` to check if every squared value exists in the second array. For example:

```js
const squareCompare = (square, compare) => {
  return square.map((x) => x ** 2).every((x) => compare.includes(x));
};

const t = squareCompare([91, 15, 54, 53, 78, 80, 91], [8281, 225, 2916, 2809, 6084, 6400, 8282]);
console.log(t);
// true

const f = squareCompare([2, 4, 2], [25, 4, 81]);
console.log(f);
// false
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done simpler.

```js
var squiredArray = [1, 4, 9, 16];

var otherArray = [1, 4, 9, 16];

var foundAll = squiredArray.every(item => {
   return otherArray.indexOf(item) >= 0;
})

console.log(foundAll);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: This method is failing the random tests as well

Comment: Looks like there is an error in your random test.  Just put random numbers manually and notice how it passes every time.

Answer (score 0):

To answer why your method failed, I'll show you mine:

```
function comp(arr1, arr2){
  let a1 = arr1.sort((a, b) => a - b).map(x => x*x);
  let a2 = arr2.sort((a, b) => a - b);

  return a2.filter(x => !a1.includes(x)).length === 0
}
```

You were using the `.includes` function which will search the list for a given item. Since you used `.includes` on `a2` which contains the correct square "8281", the function would just find the correct value "8281" twice in the filter. What you want to do is check the original passed in array `a2` and see if `a1.includes` all of its values.

Assuming these arrays are always the same size (because if they aren't it's invalid?) you can use a simple for-loop over them sorted. But, as others have mentioned, without sorting, you could just check with an `indexOf` rather than all of this filtering and including.